# Which has to be first on a HTML document Doctype or Comment?

Tags: html, w3c

In a proper html document, which one should be written first. Either the Doctype or the Comment.

Like

```
<!--
    Copyright (C) 2014 so and so pvt ltd.
    @file index.html
-->
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

Or

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--
    Copyright (C) 2014 so and so pvt ltd.
    @file index.html
-->
```

Comment: Correct your question please ? and doctype should be the first , It tells the browser what kind of document its going to render.

Comment: Besides indentation your code blocks are identical.

Comment: How does that even matter if you write the comment first or the doctype? Your comment is going to be ignored anyways.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> [**8.1 Writing HTML documents**](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#writing)
>
> Documents must consist of the following parts, in the given order:
>
> 1. Optionally, a single "BOM" (U+FEFF) character.
> 2. Any number of [comments](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#syntax-doctype) and [space characters](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#syntax-doctype).
> 3. A [DOCTYPE](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#syntax-doctype).
> 4. [...]

So it shouldn't matter if you write first the doctype and then the comment, or viceversa.

However, the HTML validator warns that if you use a comment before the doctype, IE will go into the quirks mode. So better use the doctype first.